# Unable to use Automapper

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use AutoMapper [Profile Instance](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) but keep given me error,

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;
using CashCraftApp.Model;

namespace CashCraftApp.Profile
{
    public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<RegisterNewAccountModel, Account>();

        }
    }
}
```

i have but `Automapper` and the `Automapper.Extension` installed in my Nuget

[image]

here is the error image

[image]

Comment: There should also be a compiler error, not only the red underline in the code editor. It would be a good idea to include the compiler output too in your question.

Comment: @WiktorZychla i  am also surprise, i am not getting any compiler error..

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga: If the code still compiles and executes as expected then it sounds like the code itself isn't a problem, but perhaps something in the IDE.  What message does the IDE give you when hovering the mouse cursor over the error indicator(s)?  Do those indicators persist if you close and re-open Visual Studio, and do a complete clean/rebuild of the solution?  Does the problem persist in full Visual Studio or only in VSCode?

Comment: now i am getting  `Error CS0118: 'Profile' is a namespace but is used like a type` after clean and rebuild @David

Comment: i solve it by  `AutoMapper.Profile` thanks

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error ([in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704389/unable-to-use-automapper/77704471#comment136990389_77704389)):

> Error CS0118: 'Profile' is a namespace but is used like a type

Note the namespace of your code:

```
namespace CashCraftApp.Profile
```

So `Profile` is ambiguous.  It may reference a class under `using AutoMapper`, but the compiler immediately sees that we're in a namespace called `Profile` and is interpreting it as that.  You can fully-qualify the class:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
```

Or perhaps rename your namespace to something other than `Profile`.